# Wanting to update database as I read from it calculation

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to run a calculation for a banking MS now I want to read accrued interest from a database and then update the value before conducting the next read I have currently tried this within a while loop in which the command text cannot be changed whilst the reader is open thus wont work, any ideas/solutions.
I have thought about using an array to hold the data but am unsure how to filter this out after the read

UPDATE: after introducing a cache in the form of an array I am trying to execute the update and it says that no such column product.prodid exists although this is used to read from so does exist

UPDATE 2: The code now updates to the database but incorrectly, for some reason it stores the same value in the Accrued column instead of each individual value, I can localise this error to either of the for loops, I think one solution could be to used J as a parameter and make that equal to the account ID ensuring that each row is updated then the next, could this work?

```
 private void Btn_AccInt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        command = connection.CreateCommand();

        int max = 0;
        double IntAccint = 0.0;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT balance, accrued, intrate FROM account, product WHERE account.prodid = product.prodid;";
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        double[] storedrate = new double[100];
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string AccIntrest, AccBal, Intrate;
            AccBal = reader[0].ToString();
            AccIntrest = reader[1].ToString();
            Intrate = reader[2].ToString();
            double IntAccbal, IntIntrat;
            IntAccbal = double.Parse(AccBal);
            IntAccint = double.Parse(AccIntrest);
            IntIntrat = double.Parse(Intrate);

            IntAccint = IntAccint + ((IntAccbal * IntIntrat) / 365);

            for (int i = 0; i < reader.StepCount; i++)
            {
                storedrate[i] = IntAccint;
                max = reader.StepCount;

            }

        }
        reader.Close();
        Update = connection.CreateCommand();

        for (int j = 0; j < max; j++ )
        {
            Update.CommandText = "UPDATE account SET accrued = @Accured";
            IntAccint = storedrate[j];
            Update.Parameters.AddWithValue("Accured", IntAccint);
            Update.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }


    }
```

Comment: You should either cache the changes needed and run them after the reader is closed, or use a separate database connection for the update commands.

Comment: @Zer0 I added a cache in the form of an array now the update will not execute

Comment: You have command object with select query and datareader opened with it. So you can not use the same command to execute another query until the reader is closed. So you need to create another command to execute Update query. Or you collect data of reader in some collection and loop thru it again to execute update commands.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Completed this, now the data updated is the same for each column, this is incorrect any ideas on where I may have overwriten the array or updated wrong

Comment: You should have `WHERE` clause in `UPDATE` query. Your current `UPDATE` query updates the all the rows of the table.